# JHipster OAuth2 + Keycloak user related use case

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, keycloak, okta

From various googling and reading https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#oauth2 , I gathered that in order to have mobile/social integration with JHipster generated app I should use OAuth2. **Am I right to think this way?** (I can't seem to find a clear cut answer to this)

I created a new application with JHipster v5.1.0 with OAuth2 enabled. I noticed a couple of features missing with regards to user management. Below are my questions.

1. How does a new user register a new account?
2. How does a user change password / reset forgotten password?

Hopefully someone with experience on the above can help clarify.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, Qcumber, did you find any resource to basic questions on Keycloak? I can not find any info about whether I can keep the emails of the users or how to do it?

Comment: I've not gone down to that detail yet. Sorry Jorge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For social login, yes your best option is OAuth 2.0. You can use JWT for mobile development with React Native (via [JHipster Ignite](https://github.com/ruddell/ignite-jhipster)) and Ionic (via [Ionic for JHipster](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic)), so it's not necessarily required for mobile.

For user registration and change password, you'll need to enable those options in Keycloak or Okta. This [blog post](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/25/react-spring-boot-photo-gallery-pwa) shows you how.

To summarize:

For Keycloak, you can enable registration by navigating to http://localhost:9080 and click on Administration Console. Login with admin/admin and click on the Login tab. This screen allows you to enable forgot password, remember me, and verify by email as well.

To enable self-service registration in Okta, you’ll need to navigate to the Classic UI from the Okta Developer Dashboard. There’s a link to toggle between the two in the top left corner of your screen.

Then navigate to Directory > Self-Registration and click Enable Registration. Set the default group to ROLE_USER, the Default redirect to a Custom URL with http://localhost:8080 as its value, and click Save.

NOTE: If you get an error that says 'http://localhost:8080' is not a valid redirect URI, it’s because you need to add http://localhost:8080 as a trusted redirect under Security > API > Trusted Origins. After making this change, navigate to Directory > Self-Service Registration and edit the settings to configure the custom URL again. It should work this time.

Comment: Thank you @matt-raible for clarifying.